# Changing IP address of one network changes another network's IP also

Tags: linux, ip, virtual-machine

Problem: I have two virtual networks on my VM and changing the IP on one using Network dialog also updates the other IP.

Background:

I set the IP of VMnet1 (host only) to IP 192.168.241.4

I set up the second network as VMnet18(bridged) and then set the IP to 192.168.1.18

When I do that, the IP of VMnet1 changes to 192.168.1.18! Clearly, that's not supposed to happen.

changing either IP using Network dialog updates the other IP also.

What is going on here? I have a different VM on same PC where I set up the same two networks and the IP addresses do not clobber each other. I have searched here, VMware documents and Google but have not seen this problem addressed.

PC is Windows 7, the VMs are Red Hat 7.2 Maipo and using VMware.
ETA: VMware Workstation 12 Pro 12.5.7 build-5813279

I appreciate any insight you can share. Thank you!

ETA:  the Ethernet addresses are different.

Comment: VMWare version?

Comment: VMware Workstation 12 Pro  12.5.7 build-5813279